# Calling Controller Method on a click on apex:tab

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using apex:tabPanel and have multiple apex:tab's, each tab show different data table my need is to call controller's method whenever user clicks on a tab so that respective data is loaded only when tab is clicked as otherwise if a query data for all the tabs during load of page then it effects performance adversely and it is not required too. I tried below code but this doesn't seems to be working:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="ajax" selectedTab="name1" id="tabPanel">
<apex:actionFunction name="callClass" action="{!callClass}" rerender="tabPanel" />       
<apex:tab label="My Table1" name="name1" id="tabOne" status="actionStatus" onClick="callClass()">
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myList}" var="p">
  ....
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
tab2...
tab3..
```

Comment: Did you try dynamic components in apex?

Comment: If you could post your controller it will be helpful to answer.

Comment: Controller is simple, like:
public class abc {
    
    public pagereference callClass() {
 
          ...............

}
}